# Subject-verb agreement : is or are

Tags: verbs, subjects, agreement

which one is correct? Could we consider both somehow correct?

Using idioms and expressions is appreciated.

Or

Using idioms and expressions are appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Using idioms and expressions" is a non-finite clause, and non-finite subject clauses take singular agreement, so "is" is what you need.

Comment: The second could conceivably be correct if the question was something like "*What are you using, and are expressions appreciated?*"

Answer (score 1):

I think the first one is correct, because "Using idioms and expressions" is used as a whole unit. but unsure if "appreciate" can be used passively.

Comment: I agree. What is being said is ***(The) using (of) idioms and expressions is...***. Said like that it, "is" becomes more obviously preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Using idioms and expressions **is** appreciated.

Idioms and expressions to be treated as one unit.
Moreover, we are using a descriptive verb or an adjective along with the subject.